# different type of value for each key in a hash

Tags: perl, hash

I searched in [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=different+types+for+each+key+in+a+hash+in+perl&oq=different+types+for+each+key+in+a+hash+in+perl), but I did not find anything useful in it.

Even though there are many tutorials for Perl, I did not find any tutorial which would mention a hash which has different values for each and every key?
Is such a thing possible in Perl?

For example, can there be a hash like which has 2 keys (`a`, `b`) where:

```
$myhash{"a"}=1;
$myhash{"b"}=[ 'hamnet', 'shakespeare', 'robyn', ];
```

Is the above possible?

---

I tried this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
my %x;

$x{"a"}="b";
$x{"b"}=['c','d'];

foreach (keys %x)
{
  print $_."\n";
  print "$x{$_}";
}
```

but it is outputting:

```
a
bb
ARRAY(0x1ece50)
```

I am confused about how to access the elements of this hash.

I would like to tell you all that, even though I know Perl a bit, I am a complete novice regarding hashes.

---

OK, I found one thing — to access the array inside the hash, I need to do:

```
@{$x{"b"}}
```

But as I have told you, the value of a hash can be either an array or a scalar value, so for accessing the above hash, I need to initially identify the type of the value and then access it! How can I do this?
That is, how can I identify whether a value for a key is either a scalar, an array or a hash?

Comment: The output looks fine to me. What did you expect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "Even though there are many tutorials for Perl, I did not find any tutorial which would mention a hash which has different values for each and every key? Is such a thing possible in Perl?"

You might've tried looking at the [tutorials included in your Perl distribution](http://perldoc.perl.org/index-tutorials.html), which include the [Perl Data Structures Cookbook (perldsc)](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html).  It includes a chapter on ["More Elaborate Records"](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html#MORE-ELABORATE-RECORDS), which gives examples on how to create and used a hash whose values have different types.

> "But as I have told you, the value of a hash can be either an array or a scalar value, so for accessing the above hash, I need to initially identify the type of the value and then access it! How can I do this? That is, how can I identify whether a value for a key is either a scalar, an array or a hash?"

Since you seem to be a unfamiliar with the use of [references](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) and the [`ref`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ref.html) operator, you may also want to take a look at [Mark's very short tutorial about references (perlreftut)](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html).

Note that all of these tutorials (and many more) already come with your Perl distribution, and you can access them by typing e.g.

```
perldoc perlreftut
```

on the command line.
(On some systems, you may need to install an extra package to enable the `perldoc` command.  This is highly recommended if you intend to do any Perl programming at all.)

Answer (score 3):

I think this what you want:

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl -w
 use strict;
 my %x;

 $x{"a"}="b";
 $x{"b"}=['c','d'];


 foreach my $a (keys %x)
 {
     if ( ref $x{$a} eq 'ARRAY' )
     {
         foreach my $b ( @{ $x{$a} } )
         {
             print $b."\n";
         }
     }
     else
     {
         print $x{$a}."\n";
     }
 }
```

**Output:**

```
# perl test.pl 
b
c
d
```

Check whether the hash value is an 'ARRAY' reference. If yes, then iterate over the array and print the values. Else, print the hash value rightaway.

Answer (score 1):

> so for accessing the above hash i need to initially identify the type of the value and then access it!.How can i do this? i.e., how can i identify whether a value for a key is either a singular,array ,hash?

I think a clean solution to do this is to write a simple `to_string` function (no support for deeper nested structures) which identifies wether a value is a scalar, an array reference or a hash reference (which is what `[...]` creates: a reference to an anonymous array, see [perlreftut](http://p3rl.org/perlreftut)). Read more about [ref](http://p3rl.org/perlfunc#ref).

```
sub to_string {
    my $thing = shift;

    for (ref $thing) {

        # join with comma if $thing is an array ref
        return join ', ' => @$thing when 'ARRAY';

        # join key-value list with comma if $thing is a hash ref
        return join ', ' => map {"$_ => $thing->{$_}"} keys %$thing when 'HASH';

        # else: simply return the $thing itself
        return $thing;
    }
}
```

In a simple example program

```
my %data = (
    foo => 42,
    bar => [1, 2, 3],
    baz => {a => 'yay', b => 'nay'},
);

for my $key (keys %data) {
    say "$key: " . to_string($data{$key});
}
```

it will give you this output:

```
bar: 1, 2, 3
baz: a => yay, b => nay
foo: 42
```

Note that you have to

```
use feature qw(say switch);
```

for this program. HTH! :)